# How to get `mpv --stream-record` to use icecast title as file name?

Tags: streaming, icecast, mpv

Is it possible to get `mpv` to dump a stream to separate files based on the current `icy-title` value when using `--stream-record` with an icecast stream?

`man mpv` only mentions using a fixed file name with `--record-file`, `--stream-record` `--dump-cache`.

If this is not possible directly with `mpv` what might be a possible approach to save separate files for each song in an icecast playlist rather than one huge continuous file as `--stream-record=mystream.mp3` does?

Answer (score 2):

While a solution is probably possible with a custom `mpv` lua script extension, apparently downloading to custom file names is not supported ootb.

A dedicated utility that can parse icecast titles and dump the streams to separate files is [`streamripper`](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/tutorialconsole.php). It can be installed with `apt install streamripper` on debian linuces or `brew install streamripper` on mac.

The following command will create separate files named after stream titles:

```bash
streamripper http://some-icast-server.com/stream -r 8888
```

The `-r` flag will create a relay server on port `8888`. You can listen to the relayed stream while it's been downloading with:

```bash
mpv http://localhost:8888
```

Answer (score 1):

I am currently writing a python script that can do exactly that.

I will in a few days give you the repo address to check it out, it is an internet radio client, that can also record the selected stream.

Here is a very very reducted version, that shows the principle of the whole procedure:

```python
import mpv
import time

def title0(player):
 tit1 = player.metadata.get('icy-title')
 tit2 = player.metadata.get('title')
 tit3 = player.metadata.get('TITLE')
 tit4 = player.metadata.get('artist')
 tit5 = player.metadata.get('ARTIST')
 if tit1 == None:
  tit1 = ""
 if tit2 == None:
  tit2 = ""
 if tit3 == None:
  tit3 = ""
 if tit4 == None:
  tit4 = ""
 if tit5 == None:
  tit5 = ""
 if tit4 == "" and tit5 == "":
  pavla = ""
 else:
  pavla = " - "
 tit0 = tit1+tit2+tit3+pavla+tit4+tit5
 if tit0 == '':
  tit0 = "Not Available"
 return tit0

player = mpv.MPV()
player.play('https://laterna.kafeneio.social/public/kafeneio')
player.wait_for_playback()
tit0 = "Not Available"
while tit0 == "Not Available":
 try:
  fil_format = player.file_format
  tit0 = title0(player).replace("-", " ")
  fil_nam = tit0+'.'+fil_format
 except:
  time.sleep(1)
player.stream_record = fil_nam
time.sleep(30)
```

This script will save a file with the correct format and the 'icy-title' name in the same directory as your py script.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this bash script that I wrote recenty, it is a tui internet radio client.

https://gitlab.com/christosangel/radion

Through an extra bash script there is recording functionality, and the title of the output file can be configured to be the icecast title.

After recording, the script will prompt you whether the proposed title is correct.

[image: icy.png]

**HOWEVER** the cons of this solution is that the source of the sound is not mpv itself, but the default source, so other sources will be recorded. too.

It is highly customisable, and feel free to give it a try.

As I already mentioned, I will soon finish the same project in python, without the recording drawback, and some extra functionality as well (switch easily to previous/ next station of a tag list, etc)